# How to get attribute text using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get attribute text using ajax but not working. For example

**get.php**

```
<div id="get" title="New Text"></div>
```

**html**

```
<div id="title"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=get.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var title =  $(html).find('#get').attr('title').text();
        console.log(title);
        $('#title').text(title);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.ajax` should be `$.ajax`. `url` should be a string.

Comment: ^ also, what does the `html` variable contain?

Comment: If the value of `html` is exactly what you have pasted in your first snippet, you will not be able to find your element using `$(html).find('#get')`. `#get` appears to be the root node. `find` is looking for descendants. `$(html).attr('title')` should be enough. Regardless of how you find the element, `attr('title')`, should yield a string, you should not attempt to call `.text()` on that string.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Why people downvote my question?? it is right.

Comment: Can you provide result of ajax call to your url?
I need to know what is html value here
success: function(html) {
?

Comment: `undefined` ..........

Comment: Is this url avaliable from internet?

Comment: No from my localhost server.

Comment: people not understanding my question but down voting my question.

Comment: People will downvote. Ignore it. They are voting down because they think there is too little information (and they are right)

Comment: That is not small information.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming data returned by `$.ajax()` is `<div id="get" title="New Text"></div>` the method `find()` will not work as it looks into descendant. You can directly get its attribute as

```
var title =  $(html).attr('title');
```

OR, Create a DOM element with returned data as HTML then use `find()`

```
var title =  $('<div />').html(html).find('#get').attr('title');
```

Comment: @Debar, Where is source URL?

Comment: source url is `url: 'index.php?route=get',`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = '<div id="get" title="New Text">12345</div>'
var title =  $(html).attr('title');
$('#title').text(title);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
```

If you want to get value of attribute, you should use `$.attr('attr')` instead of `$.attr('attr').text()`